# Route (other) third-party subnet via a different VPC

Tags: routing, google-cloud-platform, vpc-peering

I have a multi VPC setup with the below subnets, one per VPC.

10.154.1.0/24

10.154.2.0/24

On the 10.154.2.0/24 subnet, there is a machine which serves routes for a 10.235.0.0/16 subnet as this host is running OpenVPN. I have no problem with the (VPN) clients routing to hosts on the 10.154.1.0/24, but I cannot get the routing to work from 10.154.1.0/24 back to the 10.235.0.0/16 subnet (via the host on the second subnet).

I can not get the console to accept any sort of route to 10.235.0.0/24, across the VPC's. My system needs to use routing, NAT isn't a workable option for the VPN clients.

How can I get route traffic for the 10.235.0.0/24 subnet, from the 10.154.1.0/24 subnet?

Thanks.

Comment: and this question is related for a private issue?

Comment: @djdomi I don't really understand what you're asking me? I have been directed to Server Fault by the Google help pages.

Comment: serverfault is a business related platform, not for private purposes. In the last case you need to move your question by flagging it to move forward to superuser.com

Comment: @djdomi This is a business use case, I just GCP for various business services I provide to clients.